# Integer solutions to three variable equations.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> The minimum of x, y, z is at least 3. What are all integer solutions to
>   $$\frac1x+\frac1y-\frac1z=\frac12$$

We could see that 
$$\frac1x+\frac1y=\frac12+\frac1z$$
Now we could see if x and y are really big, then no z exists. I'm pretty sure if x=3, y<6, but how can I rigorously prove it?

Comment: You need $(1/x)+(1/y)>1/2$. So if $x=3$ you immediately get $3,4,5$ as the only possibilities for $y$, etc.

Comment: Making any progress, Baker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Prove at least one of the $x$ or $y$ should be 3 (Use proof by contradiction)